# Get UITableView Height set in Size Selector

Tags: uitableview, ios7

I have a UITableView that takes up most of a View.
I want to dynamically set the row height based on the number of rows gathered from my database.
When the UITableView is selected, Size Selector say the height is 504.

How do I get that value in code? In need that value before I populate the rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a property for the `UITableView`, such as:

```
// IBOutlet optional; you could be making the UITableView in code
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

Then, get the height like this:

```
CGFloat height = self.tableView.frame.size.height;
```

In your `UITableView` Data Source Protocol implementation, do something like this:

```
- (CGFloat)       tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
    heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    int numberOfRows = // some way to figure this out 
                       // (or maybe it's already determined)

    CGFloat height = self.tableView.frame.size.height;

    return height / numberOfRows; // or whatever your desired equation is

}
```

Anytime your data updates, a call to `[self.tableView reloadData]` will force a refresh.

Comment: Thanks! If you picked my answer, will you also please up vote it?